# Custom Win XP with permssion problems

Tags: windows-xp, installation, permissions

I'm trying to install a custom Windows XP SP3 on my HP Probook 4320s, using FAT 32 in the target partition.

The installation has gone through some problems (missing files mainly), but it was just a question of fixing it later.

And now there's another problem: During the installation, it accuses some permission issues, and after the system is installed, it doesn't accept to run any executables.

It'll always output the message "Windows cannot access the specified device path or file", even though every file can be accessed, copied and deleted using explorer, and it's a FAT 32 file system (there is no permission configuration on FAT 32 files, and there's a single, administrator user on this Windows)

It also refuses to execute explorer.exe and taskmgr.exe if I try to execute them manually, but they'll start automatically with the system or through hotkeys.

Comment: Is the copy of XP legitimate and free of malware?

Comment: Yes, the original image (the one i customized) is legitimate, and malware free, as well as the softwares used to customize it.

I have done it several times before, but this one seems to be a problem image. I have taken too much things out of it.

Comment: Sounds like you should start over.  We don't know what changes you made or even the errors you recieved